# SQL Server - Creating Distributor causes error

Tags: sql-server-2012, replication, database-replication, transactional-replication

When I try to create a Distributor on a SQL Server 2012 database I get the following error.  I have tried a lot of things over the last 6 hours and can't get anything to work.  Does anyone have any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a general connection error.

Are you configuring a remote distributor?  Is the remote distributor named "LPUAT\"?

Here is a list of things to try:

- Verify you are connecting to the right server.
- Try pinging the server by machine name.
- Try pinging the server by ip address.
- Verify the target instance SQL service is started.
- If the target instance is a named instance then make sure you are specifying a named instance when configuring distribution.
- Verify the target instance has TCP enabled.
- Verify the browser service is running on the target service if it is a named instance.
- Temporarily disable any firewalls, then try to configure distribution, to see if your being blocked by a firewall.

Comment: It's the local server that I am trying to make a Distributor and it is called LPUAT\

Comment: Try connecting to LPUAT without the \. You shouldn't need that \. If server has an instance name, you will need to add it.